# How to edit a row in Datagrid in xaml uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

First Requirement - I want to hide some columns when data is inserted (some conditions) in Datagrid

Second Requirement - When the edit button clicks on the particular row then the row is allow editing for some columns and showing save/cancel buttons instead of an edit button. When clicking on the save button, which event or method is called.

Thanks for advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

1st requirement:-

**Page.xaml**

```
<toolkit:DataGrid >
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Name"
            Tag="Name"
            Binding="{Binding Name}"
            CanUserSort="False"
            Visibility="{StaticResource hideorshow}"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridNonSortableColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Number"
            Tag="Number"
            Binding="{Binding Number}"
            CanUserSort="False"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridNonSortableColumnHeaderStyle}"/>

    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
this.Resources.Add("hideorshow", Visibility.Collapsed);
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Set value **Resource** before calling **InitializeComponent** to hide or show column in DataGrid

Thanks!!!